# Draw balls in the urn Probabilities

Tags: probability

An urn contains $7$ balls, $4$ of which are black and the rest are white.

---

1. Starting with all $7$ balls in the urn, balls are drawn randomly with replacement.

   Find the probability that among the first $5$ balls which are drawn:

   a. Exactly $2$ of them are white.

   b. At least $3$ of them are black.

For 1 a) I used Binomial Distribution:

$$\binom52\cdot\left(\frac37\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac47\right)^3$$

For 1 b) I used again Binomial distribution but because it is at least $3$ of them are black I did:

$$P(X=3)+P(X=4)=\binom53\cdot\left(\frac47\right)^3\cdot\left(\frac37\right)^2+\binom54\cdot\left(\frac47\right)^4\cdot\left(\frac37\right)^1=0.5711$$

Am I doing it right?

---

2) Starting with all $7$ balls in the urn, balls are drawn randomly without replacement until all $3$ white balls are found. What is the probability that the third white ball is found on the

a. fourth attempt? b. seventh attempt?

For $2.a$  I did:

The combinations can be:

$wwbw$

$P =\dfrac37\cdot\dfrac26\cdot\dfrac45\times\dfrac14 =\dfrac1{35}$

$wbww$

$P =\dfrac37\cdot\dfrac46\cdot\dfrac25\times\dfrac14 = \dfrac1{35}$

$bwww$

$P = \dfrac47\cdot\dfrac36\cdot\dfrac25\times\dfrac14 = \dfrac1{35}$

so : $P = \dfrac3{35}$, right?

for question $2 b)$ is there a way to do this without thinking in all possible combinations, as in the question above?

Comment: I fixed the first part of your question in order to make it readable. Feel free to fix the second part.

Comment: again, feel free to make comments on the answers if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$ is ok.

So is $2a$, though you could have done less work by just multiplying one of the expressions by $\binom31$, instead of listing the $3$ combinations.

For $2(b)$, there is a beautiful way to avoid all computations !
By symmetry, *P*(last ball is white) = *P*(first ball is white) = $\dfrac37$

**PS:**
What I am saying is that since **balls don't have preference for positions**, the probability of a white ball **being found** in **any** position = $\frac37$, the same as that for the first position.

Let's check for position $2$ as an example.

P(white ball found in position $2$) =$P(BW) + P(WW) = \frac47\cdot\frac36 + \frac37\cdot\frac26 = \frac 37$

Comment: Why is it the same - i.e. the last being white = the first being white? Thanks

Comment: Yes for the first  BWBBWBW the probability is (1/35) and for the second one WBWBBWB is also (1/35) so the only fixed place is the 7th place that should be a white ball. so the remaining 6 places can be any ball e any order so I think the answer could be (1/35)*6 Am I right?

Comment: sorry, I did a mistake , is (1/35).2 now I think it is right, can you help? thanks

Comment: No, I will explain what I was trying to get across in a PS to my ans.

Comment: So, everything is wrong?

Comment: For $2b$, the answer is $\frac37$ as explained. There is also the conventional way of computing given by Alex with the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: OK, the right way to solve the last problem is to notice that the total number of ways to select 3w and 4b is $\binom{7}{3}$. The number of ways to select balls such that the last one is white is $\binom{6}{2}$. By dividing the latter through the former you get the correct solution: $\frac{3}{7}$.